# Cmake windows mingw-w64 link OPENSSL_LIB error

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw-w64

There is much info in google about "linking with cmake", but nothing helped me.
I am trying to build webSocket server on Windows 7 x32 ang mingw-w64. It needs openssl. I've downloaded (with recomendation of cmake module) windows openssl binaries here http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
My cmake code

```
...

Set(OPENSSL_LIB_DIR "c:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/MinGW/")
Set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES "lib")
Set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")

find_library(
    OPENSSL
    NAMES  ssleau32 eau32
    PATHS  ${OPENSSL_LIB_DIR}
    #PATH_SUFFIXES lib
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
link_directories(${OPENSSL_LIB_DIR})

....

target_link_libraries(ws_examples  ${OPENSSL})
```

Tried different naming options in c:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/MinGW/ dir:

```
eay32.a
libeay32.a
liblibeay32.a
libssleay32.a
ssleay32.a
```

They are same libs but with different names.

I also tried find_package, but with the same result.

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OPENSSL
    linked by target "ws_examples" in directory G... blabla
```

Comment: ***CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.*** What variables are not found?

Comment: hmm... "OPENSSL" - 3 stroke

Comment: From the Findopenssl.cmake module (located with the cmake binaries on Progam Files (x86) it appears to be looking for: libeay32.a and ssleay32.a in mingw. Also you need to set `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` to the path containing openssl binaries not not `OPENSSL_LIB_DIR` although it appears that it should find openssl anyways because it is searching in `c:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/MinGW/` I am a little puzzled why the search fails.

Comment: Hmm. Could it be looking for the x64 binaries since you have mingw-w64?

Comment: I tried find_package many times with differernt options, that why decided find_librari. I can't understand reasons of failure of its obvios code.

Comment: mingw-w64 is also mingw for x32 and my system is 32 and other x32 projects with boost for example are ok.

Comment: - have you tried invoking the FindOpenSSL package with "REQUIRED"? that will break the configure step and tell you what exactly the package could not find.
- if still not satisfactory, copy the FindOpenSSL.cmake file into a folder of your choice and adjust the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH so that CMake uses this file. then add your own path manually and/or add message() outputs to see what's going on.

Comment: The problem solved by find_package. But frustratingly I cant understand logic of find_library.